# have a char reference an object in an array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, char

Is it possible to have a char point to an object in an array? im trying to have the characters : +,-,*,/  point to an index in my array.

I AM WELL AWARE MY SECTION BELOW IS NOT CORRECT SYNTAX. its just my way of describing what i wish to accomplish.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

            Operations plus;
            Operations minus;
            Operations multiply;
            Operations divide;
    /**********Create jumpTable*******************/
            Operations[] jumpTable = new Operations[255];
    /**********Add Object to jumpTable************/
            jumpTable[0] = new Addition();
            jumpTable[1] = new Subtraction();
            jumpTable[2] = new Multiplication();
            jumpTable[3] = new Division();
    /**********Point to index in table************/
            plus = jumpTable[0];
            minus = jumpTable[1];
            multiply = jumpTable[2];
            divide = jumpTable[3];

    //this is what im trying to do:
    //***************************************
     char +;
     char -;
     '+' = plus
     '-' = minus and etc...
   //****************************************
           double x = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
           double y = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);


        System.out.printf("%f %s %f = %f%n", x, op, y, op.Compute(x, y));

        }
    }
```

Comment: By the way, a singular name `Operation` may be more fitting than the plural `Operations` for this type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a char point to an object in an array?

Assuming that you are asking: "is it possible to use a `char` as an index for an array", then the answer is "Yes it is possible".

An index expression for an array can have *any type* that can be promoted to `int`; see [JLS 15.13](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.13).  And the `char` type can be promoted to `int`.  (You don't even need to include a typecast to make it happen.  It just works.)

Comment: Stephen, so basically there will be 2 arrays (the jumptable and array of characters). Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but I think that the answer is no.  Is this HOMEWORK?

Comment: lol no school is long behind me, im reading a book on design patterns and the best way for me to understand is by actually practicing the algorithms so this is my sort of way of trying to figure out exactly how each strategy is implemented and why

Comment: @Java Beans - I think I understand what you are saying now.  And the answer is definitely NO.  You just need one array: the "jumpTable" as you call it ... though that is a misnomer because there is no "jumping" going on here.  You then arrange that array is populated with (for example) an `Addition` instance at `jumpTable['+']`.   (I'm not saying that the extra coding involved a worthwhile ... just that that is *a* way to implement this.)

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a `Map<String, Operations>` instead of the `Operations[]`?

Also Operations should probably be called Operation.

Comment: performance is not an issue, i will def look into this. Thanks guys

Comment: @Java If performance is not an issue, why not [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Expression+evaluator)?

Comment: They are both, practically speaking, about the same performance wise.  On my machine running the array lookup version takes about 22 nano seconds per lookup while the map version takes about 30 nano seconds per lookup.  It is going to take a long time for the difference to be meaningful.  That means 500,000,000 array lookups  takes about 10 seconds, while the map version takes about 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

you can cast the char to a int or byte

```
char addition = '+';
operators[(byte)addition] = ...
```

Comment: The typecast is not necessary.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a value of type `char` every where a value of type `int` is allowed, and (apart from String concatenation and where there are two methods of both types) it works the same as the int obtained by casting.

So, `operators['+']` is identical to `operators[43]`, and similar.

If you only need `*`, `+`, `-`, `/`, you could use an array of length 6, and index into it by taking the difference to `*` (which is the first of them):

```
Operations[] jumptable = {
   new Multiplication(),  // * = 42 = '*' + 0
   new Addition(),        // + = 43 = '*' + 1
   null,                  // , = 44 
   new Subtraction(),     // - = 45 = '*' + 3
   null,                  // . = 46
   new Division()         // / = 47 = '*' + 5
};

char operator = ...;

Operation op = jumptable[operator - '*'];
```

Of course you could always make the table as big as necessary and directly index.

Comment: @Paulo thanks alot, i'm having trouble understanding what the "char operator = ...; " stands for

Comment: It is just an example of use ... you would get you char for example from reading your input or such. I just assumed that you somewhere have already the right char, and want to get the right Operation for it.

Comment: right, I want the user to input the char and it will get the correct method to compute.

Comment: So, is your problem how to let the user input a char? Maybe better ask this as a new question, since it depends from quite some factors. If you want this char as a command line parameter like in your example, you should look at the `String.charAt()` method.

Answer (score -1):

No.

A char is a Java primitive type representing a single 16-bit unicode character.

See here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: -1 - this is incorrect.  (That *is* what `char` is, but it does not imply that the answer is "No".)

Comment: I misread as pointing to an entire array object rather than just an index. Too late at night for answering on SO! Sorry!